# Easy way to align decimal place

Tags: r

The title is quite self speaking, do you know an easy way to align decimal point with R during the reporting phase ?

For instance, if I have a vector of numeric values:

c(2, 120, 12.5, 100.25, 0.1)

I would like the display to look like this:

```
  2
120
 12.5
100.25
  0.1
```

I am the first person surprised that there is no package for this in R, as I agree it is a pretty common problem. Maybe people are able to solve that using Markdown or other reporting trick ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please elaborate. Are you talking about rounding or just specifying number of decimal places? Have you tried searching the internet and stackoverflow for this? This may be a pretty common question.

Comment: Interestingly, there is no relevant answer on stack, I agree it is a common problem, maybe this problem is solved directly using reporting package like reporttools ?

Comment: `cat(c(2, 120, 12.5, 100.25, 0.1))`

Comment: A-ha, I think I understand now. How are you "printing" this report?

Comment: I am not at this step right know, but probably Markdown

Comment: the `sub` part is a bit messy because i can't figure out how to repeat the function, but the result seems ok: `c(2, 120, 12.5, 100.25, 0.1) %>% format(nsmall = 3) %>% sub("0$", " ", .) %>% sub("0 $", "  ", .) %>% sub("0  $", "   ", .) %>% str_pad(6, pad = " ") %>% paste0(collapse="\n") %>% cat`

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I decided to write a function for this purpose. It is working quite well except for the example vector, but I have no idea why, if someone can help that would be great.

```
AlignDec <- function(df, originalvar, newvar) {

  require(dplyr)

  originalvar <- enquo(originalvar) %>% quo_name()
  newvar <- enquo(newvar) %>% quo_name()

  decimalnumcount <- function(x) {

    out <- ifelse((x %% 1 != 0), nchar(strsplit(sub('.0+$', '', as.character(x)), ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][[2]]), 0)
    return(out)
  }

  IntNumCount <- function(x) {
    out <- nchar(as.character(trunc(x)))
    return(out)
  }

  df <- df %>% mutate(n_int = IntNumCount(.data[[originalvar]]), n_dec = decimalnumcount(.data[[originalvar]]), maxnint = max(n_int), maxndec = max(n_dec),
                      intpos = (maxnint - n_int), !!newvar := paste0(strrep(" ",intpos), prettyNum(.data[[originalvar]]))) %>% 
    select(-one_of(c("n_int", "n_dec", "maxnint", "maxndec", "intpos")))

  return(df)

}
```

If I test on these 2 dataframes, it's working in the 1st case, but not in the second and I have no idea why !

```
testok <- data.frame(y = c(12.1, 2, 0, 17, 1000.1, 57))
testnotok <- data.frame(y = c(2,120, 12.5, 100.25, 0.1))

test1 <- AlignDec(testok, y, z)
test2 <- AlignDec(testnotok, y, z)
```

test2 returns me this error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: subscript out of bounds.
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a special case, but the following function should do what you want. I also included a "precision" argument for specifying the maximum number of decimal places (must be greater than 0).

```
alignedDigits <- function(df, originalvar, newvar, precision = 2) {
  originalvar <- enquo(originalvar) %>% quo_name()
  newvar <- enquo(newvar) %>% quo_name()

  df[[newvar]] <- round(df[[originalvar]], digits = precision)
  split.digits <- sprintf(paste0('%0.', as.character(precision), 'f'), df[[newvar]])

  split.digits <- strsplit(split.digits, '\\.') %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    as.matrix %>% 
    t

  split.digits[,2] <- sub('0+$', '', split.digits[,2])
  split.digits[,2] <- ifelse(split.digits[,2] == '', 0, split.digits[,2])

  maxima <- apply(split.digits, 2, function(x) max(nchar(x)))
  split.digits[,1] <- sapply(split.digits[,1], function(x) paste0(paste0(rep(' ', maxima[1] - nchar(x)), collapse = ''), x))
  split.digits[,2] <- sapply(split.digits[,2], function(x) paste0(x, paste0(rep(' ', maxima[2] - nchar(x)), collapse = '')))
  final.digits <- apply(split.digits, 1, function(x) paste(x[1], x[2], sep = '.'))
  df[[newvar]] <- final.digits
  return(df)
}

testok <- data.frame(y = c(12.1, 2, 0, 17, 1000.1, 57))
testnotok <- data.frame(y = c(2,120, 12.5, 100.25, .1))

alignedDigits(testok, y, m)

       y      m
1   12.1   12.1
2    2.0    2.0
3    0.0    0.0
4   17.0   17.0
5 1000.1 1000.1
6   57.0   57.0

alignedDigits(testnotok, y, z)

       y      z
1   2.00   2.0 
2 120.00 120.0 
3  12.50  12.5 
4 100.25 100.25
5   0.10   0.1
```